# How to integrate Spring Security OAuth2 with Zuul proxy?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices, netflix-zuul

### First Question :

Spring Security OAuth2 Implemented in a single project having Authorization and Resource Server, getting access token on postman successfully, I already have implemented zuul as a seperate microservice and able to access different different microservice with the same port number. But What I am trying to implement, How will I Make use of Zuul Proxy in context to Spring Security OAuth2 ? How will I integrate Zuul Proxy with Spring Securtity OAuth2 ?

### Second Question :

How to create a custom controller in Spring Security OAuth2 ? Please give your valuable suggestions ? Thanks in Advance